# Fast creating and deleting files

Tags: google-apps-script

The problem is when I insert new file on Drive, read data then want to delete it using apps-script.
I get error "Document [ID] is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)".
The file is removed from Drive but error message is showing anyway.
If I run script in debug mode and put break in line with Drive.Files.remove() function then manually
continue debugging through remove function there is no error.
It looks like more time is needed for server to update that file was inserted?
The file is inserted with Drive.Files.insert() and option {convert: true}, from excel attachment blob.
Converted file is open with SpreadsheetApp.openById() and data copied with getDataRange().getValues().
How can I avoid that error?

edit:

Script continue after error.
Utilities.sleep(200 to 10000 ms); didn't help.

Comment: Show the script you're using - the small snippet lines you've included aren't enough to be able to tell what your issue is.

Comment: Perhaps you could delete the old files on the next read

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the issue and published a bug report to Google's issue tracker. You may check the status of it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144330142